# Error while importing csv data into mysql datababase using python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I write following code for importing csv data into mysql database

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: latin-1
#simple python csv parser that export Comma
#Separated Value data into a MySQL database.

import csv
import MySQLdb
# open the connection to the MySQL server.
# using MySQLdb
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
user='root',
passwd='root',
db='teachers')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
# read the presidents.csv file using the python
# csv module http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html
csv_data = csv.reader(file('MOCK_DATA.csv'))
# execute the for clicle and insert the csv into the
# database.
for row in csv_data:

    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO ts_info_course_info(Course_code ,Teacher_email_id ,Teacher_name ,Student_email_id ,Student_username ,Student_name ,Student_internal_roll_no , Quiz_no, Quiz_marks)'\'VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''', row)
#close the connection to the database.
cursor.close()
print "Import to MySQL is over"
```

I am getting  following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv_to_db.py", line 22, in <module>
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO ts_info_course_info(Course_code ,Teacher_email_id ,Teacher_name ,Student_email_id ,Student_username ,Student_name ,Student_internal_roll_no , Quiz_no, Quiz_marks)'\'VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''', row)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 184, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format strig
```

Please help me to remove above error.

Comment: can you post some of the sample data from `MOCK_DATA.csv`

Comment: Here is the link to MOCK_DATA.csv http://wikisend.com/download/614860/MOCK_DATA(1).csv]MOCK_DATA(1).csv

Comment: Can you post some of the sample data from `MOCK_DATA.csv` into your question.

Comment: Course_code - WCS101.1X
Teacher_email_id - ephillips0@yahoo.co.jp
Teacher_name - Edward Phillips
Student_email_id - acunningham0@bloglines.com
Student_username - acunningham0@bloglines.com
Student_name - Anne Cunningham
Student_internal_roll_no - 18204569
Quiz_no - Null                                                                               Quiz_marks - Null

Comment: Dear Noelkd above is the first row of my CSV file. I am unable to post the hole data here. But if you want to see the complete csv file you can download it from the following link. wikisend.com/download/614860/MOCK_DATA(1).csv]MOCK_DATA(1).csv Thank you in advance.

Comment: I couldn't access wiki send on the network I was on. I'll take a look later if you haven't got an answer